# How to center text vertically in a flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I just want the text to be like:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

But using flex boxes

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 200px;
}

.box div {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: auto;
}

.box div.C {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="D">D</div>
  <div class="E">E</div>
  <div class="F">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 200px;
}

.box div {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  display: flex;            /* NEW */
  align-items: center;      /* NEW */
}

.box div.C {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="D">D</div>
  <div class="E">E</div>
  <div class="F">F</div>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation

The scope of a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) is limited to a parent-child relationship. Descendants of a flex container beyond the children do not participate in flex layout and will ignore flex properties.

In your layout, the `.box` element is the flex container (the parent) and the div elements are the flex items (the children). Therefore, the `justify-content`, `align-content` and `align-items` rules apply to the divs.

However, the text is another level down. It falls outside the scope of this flex container. The text is considered a child element of the flex items / grand child of the flex container. As a result, the text cannot accept flex properties.

In CSS, text that is not explicitly wrapped by an element is algorithmically wrapped by an inline box. This makes it an *anonymous inline element* and child of the parent.

*From the CSS spec:*

> [**9.2.2.1 Anonymous inline
>   boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous)
>
> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element must be treated as an anonymous inline element.

The flexbox specification provides for similar behavior.

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex
>   container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

Therefore, the text are child elements of the flex items.

So all you need to do is make the flex item into a flex container. You can then repeat the centering rules to vertically and/or horizontally center the text.

Comment: I like this solution a lot since it still allows for the stretching of the inner divs.

Comment: As a side note, if the text contains tags it gets split up into multiple (anonymous) flex items which could lead to unexpected behavior (namely, whitespace increases / decreases where there are tags). So in this case one has to make sure to wrap the entire text in e.g. `<p></p>`.